# Image is not displaying even though it has correct source uri in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want to display profile image on profile page. When I sign in, I receive profile image information from PHP server.

So when I login, I saved it to AsyncStorage and after navigate to the profile page, I got that information from AsyncStorage. And set it to Image tag source. But image profile image is not displaying.
The weird thing is that, in that profile page, if I save the code in vscode editor (In debug state), then it shows image.  How to display image in profile image?

**What I did.**

I tried to send image url as parameter to the profile page. In the profile page, I confirmed that image url was received successfully in console. But it also didn't display image. That is my code.

**Login.js**

```
loginHandle = async () => {
  let details = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
  };
  let formBody = [];
  for (let property in details) {
    let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");
  fetch(config.auth.login, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Auth-Key': 'simplerestapi'
    },
    body: formBody
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(async (responseJson) => {
      console.log('status =>', responseJson['status']);
      if (responseJson['status'] == 200) {
        console.log('--', responseJson);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('photoURL', JSON.stringify(responseJson['photo_url']))
        console.log('profile_image', (await AsyncStorage.getItem('photoURL')).toString())
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Gallery', { 'profile': JSON.stringify(responseJson['photo_url']) })
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
}
```

**Gallery.js**

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  // const avatar = this.props.navigation.getParam('profile')  // not working. 
  // console.log('avatar=>', avatar)       (Edited)           // Exactly received parameter from Login.js
  const avatar = (await AsyncStorage.getItem('photoURL')).toString()
  this.setState({ avatar: avatar })
}

render() {
  return (
    <Image source={this.state.avatar} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image` takes an `ImageSourcePropType` for its `source` prop. Which is defined as `{uri?: string}`.

Thus it should be :

```
<Image source={{uri: this.state.avatar}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
```

More about the `source` prop here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.html#source

Comment: Thank you Oyzuu. I posted wrongly. Yes, you are right. I did like the code you post.
So `<Image source={{uri: this.state.avatar}} style="width:100,height:100"/>`
And it's value looks like "https://example.com/image/sam.png" But it is also not working.

Comment: The most important thing is that when I save code on VScode, it shows image correctly.
Just it is not working when I open that page firstly.